# Authentication and Authorization using IdentityServer4 along with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I want to implement Authentication and Authorization processes as one microservice in a new project. So I consider to use IdentityServer4 along with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.

Are there any developer who have used IdentityServer4 along with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity? Or are there those who use IdentityServer4 alone?

The aim of this question is to learn about the pros and cons of using IdentityServer.

I have some concerns if I decide to use it:

1. For example, if I encounter performance issues, I won't be able to
   interfere because it's a closed-loop system. You may consider it is
   open-source, but making code modifications could lead to other
   problems, as you can imagine.
2. if any bugs arise, I will have to wait for others to fix them.

In a nutshell:

Is it logical to implement Authentication and Authorization using our own tables(custom solution), or is it more logical to use IdentityServer4 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and customize them when necessary?

Until now, I have always implemented Authentication and Authorization on my own using custom solution on every project.

Thank you.

Comment: Use Azure AD B2C or AWS Cognito, they are managed services and cheaper too. In Cognito, your User Pool feature has a free tier of 50,000 MAUs (Monthly active users) per account. The free tier does not expire at the end of your 12 month AWS Free Tier term, and it is available to both existing and new AWS customers indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to separate out the different concerns as shown in the picture below:

[image]

If you have performance issues, then you can enable caching (in IdentityServer) and caching logic is included. In the picture, ASP.NET Core does not directly involve ASP.NET Identity, it just uses its database schema to get the necessary data. Then you can manage the users separately.

Comment: Thanks for your response.As far as I undestand,in the left picture,you implemented identityserver that is using Asp.net Identity Entities against shared db between this identityserver api and User Management Service (mvc app).Jwt access token and Id Token is being generated by this IdentityServer via login endpoint.But Register,ForgotPassword,ResetPassword is against User management service web app right?Shortly you seperated user creation and login via OAuth2 part right?

Comment: I mean you can only let IdentityServer do the login of users, all the other things you can redirect the user to the ASP.NET Identity side of your system (the right side) 

In fact, if I am not incorrect, IdentityServer only needs READ-ONLY access so that database (it never changes anything in that database. Sure, it needs some other tables for housekeeping, but that can be located elsewhere. I think its important to separate the responsibilities in your architecture, otherwise its hard to reason about it.